# how to make your bot send what message the user send when an error happens

Tags: python, discord.py, bots, message, custom-error-handling

i was trying to code what to do when an error happens but i always get this when an error actually happen

```
error found by: gHoSt FaCe#xxxx, in: admins-chat,  the message was: <Message id=1023531531035230208 channel=<TextChannel id=1019911370512289802 name='admins-chat' position=22 nsfw=False news=False category_id=1019911233077526578> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<Member id=593874348524175405 name='gHoSt FaCe' discriminator='2856' bot=False nick=None guild=<Guild id=744535554036858901 name='MJSH21' shard_id=0 chunked=True member_count=53>> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>, the error: Member "test" not found.
```

code:

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    channel = client.get_channel(xxxxxxxx)
    await channel.send(f'error found by: {str(ctx.author)}, in: {str(ctx.channel)},  the message was: {str(ctx.message)}, the error: {str(error)}')
    await ctx.send(f"An error occured: {str(error)} ")
```

every time it gets to the message it just sends a lot of weird stuff
it still works but how can i remove the weird stuff and only send the message instead of all of that weird stuff

imports:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord.member
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import discord
import os
import time
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, guild_only, Bot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put `ctx.message` alone, which is what returns all the weird stuff
in order to remove the weird stuff you just add `.content` making it `ctx.message.content`

Also you don't need to convert anything to a string it will work without it

The code will look like this

```py
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx:commands.Context, error):
    channel = bot.get_channel(xxxxxxxx)
    await channel.send(f'error found by: {ctx.author}, in: {ctx.channel},  the message was: {ctx.message.content}, the error: {error}')
    await ctx.send(f"An error occured: {str(error)} ")
```

It's better if you add the `:commands.Context` to `ctx` in order to understand what else you can do